# how to loop through a string and see if "1" is an element in the str?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

if orderIds has a present element called "1"
then buy1 = true

```
orderIds = ""

for idx = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
    strSuffix = idx == strategy.opentrades - 1 ? "" : ", "
    orderIds += strategy.opentrades.entry_id(idx) + strSuffix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
orderIds = ""

for idx = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
    strSuffix = idx == strategy.opentrades - 1 ? "" : ", "
    orderIds += strategy.opentrades.entry_id(idx) + strSuffix

//Show result on the chart
label.new(bar_index, high, orderIds)


// if your order ID is "1" then cakes = 12222 
cakes = 10000

if str.contains(orderIds, '1')
    cakes := 12222

plot(cakes)
```